# Dim LEDS with button

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pycharm, raspberry-pi4

I want to dim all the LEDS with one button. I work with a Raspberry Pi 4 and Pycharm. I have to work with Pycharm so I can't do it in the Raspberry Pi. Can someone help me? This is my code. It is **def button_4()**

The pin from the button is connected with the PWM pinout from the Pi. All the leds are just connected with a pinout from the Pi.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env

__author__ = "Zino Henderickx"
__version__ = "1.3"

# LIBRARIES
from gpiozero import LED
from gpiozero import Button
from gpiozero.pins.pigpio import PiGPIOFactory
import multiprocessing
import time
from gpiozero import PWMLED

IP = PiGPIOFactory('192.168.0.207')


# LED's
AMOUNT_LEDS = 4
LED1 = LED(26, pin_factory=IP)
LED2 = LED(19, pin_factory=IP)
LED3 = LED(6, pin_factory=IP)
LED4 = LED(11, pin_factory=IP)

#PWM




# BUTTONS
AMOUNT_BUTTONS = 4
BUTTON1 = Button(14, pin_factory=IP)
BUTTON2 = Button(16, pin_factory=IP)
BUTTON3 = Button(12, pin_factory=IP)
BUTTON4 = Button(23, pin_factory=IP)


def turn_leds_on():
    LED1.on()
    LED2.on()
    LED3.on()
    LED4.on()


def turn_leds_off():
    LED1.off()
    LED2.off()
    LED3.off()
    LED4.off()


def let_leds_blink():
    LED1.blink()
    LED2.blink()
    LED3.blink()
    LED4.blink()


def button_1():
    while True:
        if BUTTON1.value == 1 and LED1.value == 0:
            turn_leds_on()
            time.sleep(0.25)
        if BUTTON1.value == 1 and LED1.value == 1:
            turn_leds_off()
            time.sleep(0.25)


def button_2():
    while True:
        if BUTTON2.value == 1 and LED3.value == 0:
            LED3.on()
            LED4.on()
            time.sleep(0.25)
        if BUTTON2.value == 1 and LED3.value == 1:
            LED3.off()
            LED4.off()
            time.sleep(0.25)


def button_3():
    while True:
        if BUTTON3.value == 1 and LED1.value == 0:
            turn_leds_on()
            PWMLED(12, True, 0.50, 100)
            time.sleep(0.25)
        if BUTTON3.value == 1 and LED1.value == 1:
            turn_leds_off()
            time.sleep(0.25)


def button_4():
    while True:
        if BUTTON4.value == 1 and LED1.value == 1:
            time.sleep(30)
            turn_leds_off()
        if BUTTON4.value == 1 and LED2.value == 1:
            time.sleep(30)
            turn_leds_off()
        if BUTTON4.value == 1 and LED3.value == 1:
            time.sleep(30)
            turn_leds_off()
        if BUTTON4.value == 1 and LED4.value == 1:
            time.sleep(30)
            turn_leds_off()
        if BUTTON4.value == 1 and LED1.value == 0:
            turn_leds_on()
            time.sleep(30)
            let_leds_blink()
            time.sleep(5)
            turn_leds_off()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    x1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=button_1)
    x2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=button_2)
    x3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=button_3)
    x4 = multiprocessing.Process(target=button_4)
    x1.start()
    x2.start()
    x3.start()
    x4.start()
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are doing. You want one button to dim all LEDs but you have 4 buttons?

Comment: I have pycharm on rpi3 running ubuntu - can't remember the installation details but this looks promising https://www.element14.com/community/community/raspberry-pi/blog/2019/09/12/installing-pycharm-on-raspberry-pi

Comment: Yes, every button has a function. And for a task button 3 has to DIM all the leds. button 1 or 2 or 3 has other functions. Maybe it is my pinout or something? Because button 3 is connected to the PWM pin on the Pi.